# How to handle the case of Empty Sets in Negated Statements used in proofs.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Consider the following statement:

$$ A \subseteq B $$

It's negation is the following

$$ A \not \subseteq B$$

Negating statements can be required in proofs by contraposition, for example.

---

Now consider the case that $A$ is empty, $A=\emptyset$.

The first statement $A \subseteq B$ is fine, since the empty set is a subset of all sets (but not an element).

The second statement $A \not \subseteq B$ is more interesting. It says $A$ is not a subset of $B$, but we know the empty set is a subset of all sets.

**Question 1: How should I proceed?** Do I simply state that any following steps based on the negation are only valid for non-empty $A$? Do I need to do more?

---

Now consider a related statement,

$$A = B$$

and its negation

$$ A \neq B$$

**Question 2:** Does the case of empty set require caution here? I don't think it does, but I may be wrong.

Comment: 1) If the premise in a proposition is false, then the proposition is vacuously true. So in a proof by contrapositive, if we have that ¬ p is false, we immediately obtain that ¬ p → ¬q is true. This is equivalent to noting that if a conclusion in an implication is true, so q → p, where p is true, is itself true. ( Its only false when q is true and p is false) So, in the case where you have p → A ⊆ B, and A is empty, If you consider the contraposive- it is true vacuously.

Comment: 2) Empty set often requires caution, and many times is proven seperately as a special case; or we stregnthen the hypothesis to exclude it. I dont believe any of these precautions are needed for A = B, though, or its negation.

Comment: For **question 1**, everything seems fine to me: $\emptyset \subseteq B$ is true, while the negation $\emptyset \nsubseteq B$ is false as expected.